# Is there a command to send private message to all members of a group?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there any way to make a command send a private message to all members of the discord group using discord.js?

Exemple: `/private TEST`

This message is sent to everyone in the group in private chat instead of channel chat.

Comment: By "group" you mean guild or DM group? Because bots can't join DM groups, unless they're self-bots, but that could get you banned from Discord

Comment: By guild example "bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   member.send("Olá, bem-vindo ao discord do StealMC."); " http://prntscr.com/kfabc0
This code sends this message privately to all who enter the server, I want a command that sends message by private to all the members of the server the same function as that, the difference would be the command I could type / test MESSAGE THAT EVERYONE GO RECEIVE and everyone on the server will receive this message in private.
Sorry, I'm Brazilian and I'm using the translator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through [`Guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members).
When you receive a message that starts with `/private`, you take the rest and send it to every member of the guild by using [`Guild.members.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).
Here's a quick example:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('/private')) {
    let text = msg.content.slice('/private'.length); // cuts off the /private part
    msg.guild.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);
    });
  }
});
```

This is just a basic implementation, you can obviously use this concept with your command checks or modify that by adding additional text and so on.

Hope this solves the problem for you, let me know if you have any further questions :)

Comment: heyCould you give me another hand? I want to make an example command "/ log TEST", I want this text that I typed go to a channel of my choice

Comment: Replace `/private` with `/log`, then use `msg.guild.channels.find('name', 'channel_name_here')` to find your channel. If the channel exists, you can `channel.send(text)`. If you have further problems with this, please open a new question. If my answer worked for you, you can accept it to close the thread ;)

Comment: Could you send the code ready? I made a topic about this doubt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753661/sending-text-to-a-channel-i-chose?noredirect=1#comment90467130_51753661

Comment: `member.id != client.user.id` is unnecessary since `!member.user.bot` is always false for the bot client.

Answer (score 4):

The updated code for discord.js v12 is just adding cache to the forEach.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('/private')) {
    let text = msg.content.slice('/private'.length); // cuts off the /private part
    msg.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is, now with cache we haven't all member but just all who have send a message ressently I think ?

Comment: If you need to fetch all members and bypass cache, use [GuildMemberManager#fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) 
`guild.members.fetch().then(console.log).catch(console.error);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but nothing happen :s 
did you test your code ? I can't fetch anything

Comment: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\discordSendMessages\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:317:16
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Documents\Code\discordSendMessages\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:83:7)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT'
}

Comment: Nothing wrong with code, you need the members intent on in the discord developers portal.