# Command to send text to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that sends the text to a channel of my choosing.
Example:

```
!command "text"
```

Then the `"text"` is sent to the channel I chose.

Comment: What do you have so far for code?

Comment: msg.guild.channels.find('name', 'channel_name_here') to find your channel. If the channel exists, you can channel.send(text)

Comment: You should put your code directly into the question and use the code formatter.  It'll help make your question more readable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post your code, so that you can format it and make it readable. What happens when you run the code? What do you expect to happen instead? Any errors? What specifically do you have problems with?

Comment: Ready was edited, take a look now. I'm sorry, I'm Brazilian and I'm using the translator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the same code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705319/is-there-a-command-to-send-private-message-to-all-members-of-a-discordjs-group), I just modified a little part as I told you in the comments.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('/log')) {
    let text = msg.content.slice('/log'.length); // cuts off the /log part
    let channel = msg.guild.channels.find('name', 'channel_name_here');
    if (channel) channel.send(text);
    else msg.reply("Can't find channel");
});
```